# Same ActionListener for Different Buttons - Best Practices

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

The code works, but I wanted to know whether this was the best way/most recommended way of adding an actionListener when the buttons are performing the same task on different files. I've read the debate between making a class implement the ActionLister interface vs. adding an anonymous actionListener class to each button. Neither approach seemed to fit this situation. Here is my code with irrelevant bits left out:

```
public class ABC {
    public ABC() {
        // constructor here
    }

    private JMenuBar createMenuBar() {
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu menu1 = new JMenu("File");
        menuBar.add(menu1);

        JRadioButtonMenuItem P1 = new JRadioButtonMenuItem();
        JRadioButtonMenuItem P2 = new JRadioButtonMenuItem();

        P1.addActionListener(fileSelectionListener);
        P2.addActionListener(fileSelectionListener);
        P1.setText("P1");
        P2.setText("P2");
        menu1.add(P1);
        menu1.add(P2);

        return menuBar;
    }

    ActionListener fileSelectionListener = new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JRadioButtonMenuItem source = (JRadioButtonMenuItem) e.getSource();
            String a = source.getText();
            loadFile(a);
        }
    };

    private void loadFile(String a) {
        // implementation of method
    }
    // adding things to the frame
    // main method
}
```

Comment: This is a stylistic issue. For myself, I like to use `AbstractAction`, and to declare my AbstractAction inner classes at the end of the class file. If you need to use your listener twice, you can either use a method variable if you're only adding your listener in set up, or in a class field if you'll need it again later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way? Probably not by most people's standards. In my eyes? Yeah, it's probably the best way. You made a reusable instance of an ActionListener because you use it more than once. To me it's the same thing as making the class extend ActionListener.

Most recommended takes us into the depths of the debate so I probably wouldn't stray too far into there ;)

You approach is definitely faster than adding an anonymous listener to each button.